# nodejs simple TCP chat, server gets no client messages

Tags: node.js, tcp, chat

I'm new to nodejs, and I need to build an uptime monitoring system, using TCP server and client and keepalive connection. At the moment I try to build to base of this system, but the server doesn't display any messages from the client. Any idea where I made a fault?

server:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (conn)
{
conn.write('Hello here server');
}

).listen(1234);

server.on('data', function (data)
{
console.log('client: ' + data);
});
```

client:

```
    var net = require('net');

    var client = net.connect({port: 1234}, function(){
    console.log('client connect');
    });
    client.setEncoding('utf8');

    client.write('hello here client');

    client.on('data', function (data)
    {
        console.log('server: ' + data);


    });
```

Any idea, why the server doesn't get any output of the messages the client send? As you may see, it's nearly the same as a chat, but I need to use keep-alive, connection in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your server to listen for data inside the `createServer`:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer(function (conn) {
    conn.write('Hello here server');

    conn.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log('client: ' + data);
    });
}

).listen(1234);
```

Comment: great, thanks, works fine. After I stopped the client the server got an error  event `events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:837:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:544:26)` any idea how to get the server not shutting down, after a client disconnected? Can the server handle multiple clients?

Comment: What error? Please consider to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: accepted answer, will open a new question case for this, thanks!

Comment: Well, I think it's better you end the client after sending the message use something like `client.end()`